# Как продолжить цикл из другого метода

Tags: java, циклы, методы, java-8

Хочу чтобы из места обозначенного комментарием `//это место` "перекинуло" в цикл обозначенного `//этот цикл`, при том, что они находятся в разных методах. Если что ниже приведённый код не работает и как его исправить?

```
public Token nextToken()
{
    position = skipWhitespaces(code, position);
    if (position == -1) {
        goto mainLoop; //здесь ошибка //это место
        //System.exit(0);
        return null;
    }
    StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
    char current = code.toCharArray()[position];
    while (current != ' ')
    {
        buffer.append(current);
        position++;
        if (position >= code.length()) {
            //end of parsing input string
            break;
        }
        current = code.toCharArray()[position];
    }
    //System.out.println(buffer.toString());
    TokenType tokentype = getTokenTypeByName(buffer.toString());
    if (tokentype == null) throw new RuntimeException(buffer.toString());
    addToken(tokentype, buffer.toString());
    return new Token(buffer.toString(), tokentype);
}
public void tokenize(String[] input)
{
    for (String thisStr : input)
    {
        code = thisStr;
        mainLoop:for (position = skipWhitespaces(code, 0); position < code.length(); position++) //этот цикл
        {
            //System.out.println(position);
            if (position == -1) System.exit(0);
            Token thisToken = nextToken();
            //System.out.println(thisToken.text + '\t' + thisToken.getName());
            if (thisToken == null) return;
            parseToken(thisToken);
        }
    }
}
```

Если что задавайте вопросы

Comment: "_как его исправить?_" - никак. Точнее, этот код исправить невозможно, переписывайте алгоритм без таких фокусов.

Comment: Вынесите свой цикл, к которому пытаетесь обратиться, в отдельный приватный метод и вызывайте этот метод из двух своих уже написанных методов. Вполне нормальная практика - выносить общий код в отдельные методы. В чем вопрос то?

Comment: Если код не работает или работает, но неправильно, необходимо объяснить что именно не работает, и что должно быть чтобы код работал. Без подробного описания проблемы невозможно судить о том работает код или нет. Привели пример кода и напиши тесты покрывающие не работающий код.